# How could I go about getting some sound design work on an indie film this summer?

Tags: work, finding-work

I am studying at University this summer, but could really do with some working experience in sound design for an indie film. I am based in the UK and am willing to offer my services for free, I just don't know how to go about finding any work...

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people underestimate the power of Linkedin. But if you build a solid profile, with links to portfolio and website you only have to find the right people in there. Joining specialized groups and taking part in their discussions is usually the easiest way.

Comment: I agree. It is about social networks. Good example of this is http://takemetosiliconvalley.com/ - This guy take Job in about one week in sunny California :) Thumbs up!

Comment: Haha, that website/cover letter is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking on forum's and websites for Indie films and offer your services to people making the films. Or websites like Mandy- a job posting website- you often get people looking for voluntary sound designers on there.

Answer (score 1):

Mandy.com would be your best bet bro.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggesting to be proactive - no crying on forums :)

Look at twitter, use social networks, try to advertise on boards in clubs etc.

Of course it is long term run but who said that Life is easy?

Try to be more educated - there is a lot of blogs around with many suggestions. If you know about any company which doing sound design why you do not send them CV with examples of your work?

Wish you good luck!!!

Comment: The latter can be tricky in some instances due to plausible deniability (especially larger studio entities) - deniability in that they didn't 'steal' or 'borrow' from something you showed them, whether intentionally or unintentionally.  So some places may not look at demo material, not to be taken as an offense to you though - it's just a legal precaution some have to take.  I've been on the receiving end of one of those situations before.  Unfortunately, for both sides, it's just the cost of doing careful business in the creative market.

Answer (score 0):

try to Identify the screen and media or film courses that the universities in your area provide and try and hook up with some of the film makers there.

i know the schools in Melbourne all have crewing nights that are open to the public where the film makers pitch their ideas and let the audience know what roles they are trying to fill.
usually its for 3rd year or above like masters films too, so they are often very high quality films.